# Is there a side menu plugin using javascript and html5 can implement google homepage on iPhone

Tags: javascript, html

I want to implement a side menu app using html5 and javascript like the google home page on iphone. some one who know a plugin can do this?

[image: homepage]

[image: when click the side menu button]

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this library may help you. It uses jQuery.

http://www.berriart.com/sidr/

Comment: thank you very much. It seems as cool as google. But have you ever use d it? It if for free all?

Comment: but when I slide the menu the content is moving too.